# XML schema delete section when saving

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

I am creating a XML schema (first time doing so). I am working with eclipse to validate a XML for a project. While fixing the problem on eclipse, ellipse will automatically erase a large chunk of my project I have worked on it for hours and could not over come this, this is my original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:sample="http://www.example" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- define nodeName -->

    <xsd:element name="nodeName" >
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="struct">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="attribute" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="interface">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="attribute" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="channel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="direction" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="component">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="attribute" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="field" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="constructor">
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="behaviour">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name=send minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="identifier" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:attribute name="on" type="xsd:string" />
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name=receive minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="identifier" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:attribute name="from" type="xsd:string" />
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name=variable minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:attribute name="allocation" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:attribute name="bindingTo" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name=print minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
                                    <xsd:attribute name="variable" type="xsd:string" />
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="instance">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="component" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="connect">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="from minOccurs=" 1 maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="on" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="on minOccurs=" 1 maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="on" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="interNodeConnect">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="from minOccurs=" 1 maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="on" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="on minOccurs=" 1 maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:attribute name="on" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="direction" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="otherNode" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd.schema>
```

To put it simply, every part of this is explaining some form of wireless sensor network. I need to validate my system with one of each of these types, however, everything after interface is removed when I try to save this file.

Comment: Which editor are you using to edit this? Is anything supposed to be modifying this file for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in your schema. (I was able to identify them with NetBeans's "Validate XML" functionality, maybe eclipse has something like that too):

- the closing tag of the root element should be `</xsd:schema>` instead of `</xsd.schema>`
- several attribute values are not enclosed in `"`s, e.g. in `component/behaviour`:

  ```
  <xsd:element name=send minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  ```

  Has to be replaced with

  ```
  <xsd:element name="send" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  ```

  BTW: its the same for all subelements of `component/behaviour`
- There are several attribute values that not closed correctly:

  ```
  <xsd:element name="from minOccurs=" 1 maxOccurs="1">
  ```

  Has to be replaced with

  ```
  <xsd:element name="from" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  ```

Of course "fix" functionality can fix some errors, but it cannot fix everything.

---

**PS: Tipp:** You have several "anonymus" complex types, that look the same. You can give complex types a name too. You can also extend them. (see http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex.asp) This would be a good way to reduce the amount of code you have to write.